# How to download the latest version of cordova.js?

Tags: cordova

When clicking on the DOWNLOAD icon of the latest version of cordova(Cordova version 4.0.0), it is getting navigated to the bottom of the same page, where it is written like

"It is recommended that the cordova CLI be installed from npm rather than downloading this .zip version. For more information on installing the npm version see the **Command-Line Interface** section of the documentation."

I have used cordova version 2.9.1 in developing my application. Later i got warning from google play store to use the updated version of cordova, since my app is having some kind of vulnerabilities.

Can someone help me out to find a way to download the latest version of apache cordova( at least the version 3.5)?

-Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the archive for [cordova version](http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/)

It seems that it stop at the v3.4. The 3.5 and 3.6 are not available. To install the v4 just use the [CLI](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0//guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)